# Are all finite dimensional algebras over the real numbers `Banach algebra'-able

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

Suppose that $A$ is a finite dimensional algebra over the real or complex numbers. Then $A$ has a natural topology induced from it being a finite dimensional vector space. Is it always true that there is a norm on $A$ satisfying $\| MN \| \leq \| M \| \| N \|$, or are there some finite dimensional algebras which aren't `Banachable'? If we weaken the norm to not being complete, do we obtain stronger results?

Comment: Every finite dimensional normed space is complete, so there is no weakening/strengthening in that direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since $A$ is a finite-dimensional vector space, we can define a norm (any $\ell^p$-norm will do).  Since $A$ is finite-dimensional, any linear operator is continuous with respect to this norm.  To each $a\in A$ we can associate a linear map $x\mapsto ax$. Thus considering $A$ as a subalgebra of $L(A)$ with the operator norm, we obtain a norm on $A$ which is submultiplicative.

Comment: I'm currently away from the PC, I'll expand on this when I return

Comment: Of course! I forgot that any Banach space with a continuous multiplication structure has an equivalent norm upon which it is a Banach algebra. I should really reread Rudin at some point.

Comment: @JacobDenson yeah I definitely got the idea from the first few pages of chapter 10